# How to print the output in text file in specific order using Batch scipt

Tags: batch-file

I am currently working on batch script to find the search string from log file and am redirected output to text file and using VB script I am mailing that text file to our team.

what is my actual query is how can I print the output in as same as log file.

In log file the real thing is like

```
Summary Report:-

Source statistics:
Unprocessed:          0
Quarantined:          0
With Failures:        0
Imported:             2
Total Sources:        2

Message statistics:
Unprocessed:          0
Failed:               0
Success:           4865
Excluded:             0
Ignored:              0
Total Messages:    4865
```

My output is Coming like:

```
=========================================================================
Summary Report:-
Source statistics:
Message statistics:
Unprocessed:          0
Unprocessed:          0
Quarantined:          0
With Failures:        0
Imported:             2
Total Sources:        2

Failed:               0
Success:           4865
Excluded:             0
Ignored:              0
Total Messages:    4666
Total Messages:     199
Total Sources:        2
Total Messages:    4865.
```

This is my code

```
@echo off

echo. > C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log
set dirpath="My path is here"

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b "%dirpath%"') do set recent=%%x

findstr /i "\<^Summary Report:-\> \<statistics:\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B "\<^Source statistics:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B "\<Unprocessed:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B "\<\Quarantined:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /i "\<Failures:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B "\<Imported:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /i "\<Sources:\>" "Mypath\%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<^Message statistics:$\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<Failed:\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<Success:\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<Excluded:\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<Ignored:\>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<Total Messages:$\>" "Mypath%recent%"  >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

findstr /B  "\<^No items to report>" "Mypath%recent%" >> C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log

call C:\Users\\Pictures\AutoEmailSend.vbs

Exit 0
```

Please help me to get the output in as same as log file order. what technic we have to use here to get user defined output.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand: why don't you send the log file itself? Or a log part repeat and  you want extract the last (or another particular) occurrence of text between `Summary Report:-` and `Total Messages:` lines?

Comment: You should show more of the original file and describe what you want to eliminate. There may be much better ways to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you know what is in your log file - but test this to see if it gives you what you are after.

The order of the terms is not important - they will appear in the same order as the input file.

```
@echo off

set dirpath="My path is here"

(
echo ^^$
echo Summary Report:
echo Source statistics:
echo Unprocessed:
echo Quarantined:
echo With Failures:
echo Imported:
echo Total Sources:
echo Message statistics:
echo Unprocessed:
echo Failed:
echo Success:
echo Excluded:
echo Ignored:
echo Total Messages:
)> "%temp%\findstr.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b "%dirpath%"') do set "recent=%%x"

findstr /i /g:"%temp%\findstr.txt" "%dirpath%\%recent%" > "C:\Users\Pictures\scripts\test.log"

del "%temp%\findstr.txt"
call "C:\Users\Pictures\AutoEmailSend.vbs"
Exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the strings in one `findstr` using multiple `/c`, here's an example:

```
findstr /i /c:"A" /c:"B" /c:"C" /c:"D" inputfile >>log
```

To match string start use regexp:

```
findstr /i /r /c:"^A" /c:"^B" /c:"^C" /c:"^D" inputfile >>log
```

If your source strings contain special characters like `^$.*[]\><` prepend each one with `\`.